# Galaxy A71 stops charging

Tags: charging

My A71 will after sometime stop charging. Rebooting it fixes the issue for awhile. Anyone else experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: Could be a thermal problem if the battery is going too hot while charging. By rebooting you give the battery a minute or two to cool down below the critical temperature. Try a different charger with less power (e.g. only 1.0 or 1.5A at 5V) and place the phone vertically on a hard surface to optimize cooling of the phone.

Comment: @Robert I don't think it's a thermal problem. I usually notice it when I go to plug it in at night that it won't charge until I reboot it. Once rebooted it will charge to 100%.

Comment: When you say "stop charging" does that mean the icon changes like no power supply is connected or is just the battery percentage not increasing as it would be expected?

Comment: @Robert The icon changes like no power supply is connected. Reconnecting it and even different power supplies and cables don't help. A reboot is the only fix I've found.

Comment: It sounds like a software issue, I wouldn't know what else would change the state from rebooting. Did it always do that or randomly started after an update? It may be stopping as a safety measure but it could also be a defect temperature sensor or thermal fuse or some other protection mechanism that's overreacting.

Comment: @Foxyz It's been doing it for a couple of months.  Not sure if it started after an update. Its been a good phone otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this issue before. For him it was the battery. Use a Battery Health Checker app to see what the issue is. Replace the battery everything should be just fine

Oh and before buying a battery maybe try using a different adapter and try cleaning the charging port. Just for the safe side

Comment: I downloaded Accubattey. We'll see what it comes up with.

Comment: Battery health is down to 82%. New battery seems cheap enough and easy enough to replace.